# fetch latest database entry that has a specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently developing a website for a friend and I ran into an issue that I am not able to solve to my satisfaction.

I was asked to log the user logins, and my approach was, to create a table that holds the columns:

- id
- user_id
- login_time
- login_ip

Now if the table lookes something like this:
**id -- user_id -- login_time --------------- login_ip**
1 ----- 1 --------- 2016-05-29 17:21:47 --- 11.0.0.1
2 ----- 1 --------- 2016-05-29 17:22:12 --- 11.0.0.1
3 ----- 2 --------- 2016-05-29 17:23:49 --- 11.0.0.1
4 ----- 3 --------- 2016-05-29 17:25:57 --- 11.0.0.1
5 ----- 2 --------- 2016-05-29 17:28:34 --- 11.0.0.1
**6 ----- 1 --------- 2016-05-29 17:30:35 --- 11.0.0.1**
7 ----- 3 --------- 2016-05-29 17:31:28 --- 11.0.0.1
8 ----- 3 --------- 2016-05-29 17:31:58 --- 11.0.0.1
9 ----- 2 --------- 2016-05-29 17:44:29 --- 11.0.0.1

How do I get the data from row 6 most efficiently? As this is the last time the user with "the user_id" of 1 logged in, is there a way to "ask" mysql to get the latest entry that has the "user_id = 1"?
My current approach would be

```
("SELECT * FROM login_tracking WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
```

That is not a problem if tha database is small, but if it grows larger, it will be inefficient in my eyes.

Or would it be a better option to add the "login_time" and the "login_ip" to the users table and get the information from there, when the user last logged in and keep the same + the past login entries in the "login_tracking" table?

Comment: *"How do I get the data from row 6 most efficiently?"*  `WHERE user_id = 1 and id =6` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: *"is there a way to "ask" mysql to get the latest entry that has the "user_id = 1"* - You could order by (most recent) date and time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well in this case I know the ID of the row, but I want to get it dynamically. And fetching all and ordering by any of the values is what I was trying not to do as it is not efficient in my eyes. I would like to get to the value without manually first cutting down all the things I don't need.

Comment: you've been given an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re original select is the best option:

```
select * from login_tracking where user_id = 1 order by id desc limit 1
```

But, be aware to create an index on both columns id and user_id:

```
create index two_cokumn_index on login_tracking (id , user_id );
```

This will really increase query performance.

Comment: I had a look into multi column indexes as I never dealt with them before. From what I found it looks like this is the solution that would work best. Thanks.
Just as a quick side-question, do you know any good tutorial/resource to get more information about that topic?

Comment: Richard, dealing with indexes on any database (mysql, oracle, postgres, etc) is an important aspect of performance monitoring and improving. I spend lots of hours in my life reading about it. So, its not that simple think, but not that complicated. It´s important to understand the storage engine you are using and the kind of index.

Comment: Take a look at Mysql docs. There´s lots of good infos there. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks Tiago, I'll have a look!